# Prove that for a convergent sequence $(a_n)$ of real numbers $ inf(a_n) \le \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = a \le sup(a_n)$ (not by contradiction)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

I was able to prove that by contradiction, showing that (for example) if $a > sup(a_n) = s$, then also $s$ is a limit of the sequence $(a_n)$.

I was wondering if it can be proved in some other way.

I actually proved it starting from the cases $a < a_n$ and $a \ge a_n$ for all $n$, but I think I cannot do that as $(a_n)$ has infinitely many elements and in some sense the argument is circular.

Comment: Can you prove directly that if $a_n\le M$, then $a\le M$?

Comment: I would prove that using the same argument as before, so correct me if I'm wrong: either $a \ge a_n \forall n$ or $a<a_n$ for some $n$. In the latter case, $a < M$. In the first case, $a$ is an upper bound, and since it's also the limit, for every $\epsilon >0$, there is an $a_n$ s.t. $a_n > a - \epsilon$. Therefore $a = M = sup(a_n)$

Comment: I never said that $M$ was the sup. I asked you for a general argument. But it's only a slight modification of what you have. I'll post an answer because you don't need to consider these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more general argument: If $a_n\le M$ for all $n$ and $a_n\to a$, then $a\le M$ as well. We'll give a direct proof.

Given any $\epsilon>0$, we know that there is an $N$ so that $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$. So this means that $-\epsilon<a_n-a<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$. In particular,  we find that
$$a-\epsilon<a_N\le M.$$
This tells us that $a<M+\epsilon$. But $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, and so $a\le M$.

Comment: Yes, the fact is that I am not able to prove tha last passage ($a\le M+\epsilon\rightarrow a\le M$) without relying on contradiction. Also, why is $a\le M+\epsilon$ and not $a < M+\epsilon$ ?

Comment: You're right about the inequality sign, although what I have (had) isn't wrong. You're also right that the "usual" justification for the last step is (at least intuitively) done by contradiction. But let's see: It's trichotomy. Suppose $x$ is less than all positive numbers. A positive number cannot be less than itself, so it cannot be less than all positive numbers. That means $x$ must be $0$ or negative. Strictly speaking, that's not proof by contradiction, is it? :)

Comment: Thanks. In fact your proof sounds to me way more clear and intuitive than that done by contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with

$\tag 1 \text{inf}(a_n) \le \text{sup}(a_n)$

and

$\tag 2 \lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n = a $

we need direct proofs of the following

$\tag 3 \text{inf}(a_n) \le a$

and

$\tag 4 a \le \text{sup}(a_n)$

$\text{(3)}$: Let $\alpha = \text{inf}(a_n)$ and $b_n = a_n-\gamma$. Once we directly prove that

$\tag 5 \lim_{n\to+\infty} b_n = a - \gamma$

it is easy to argue that $\text{(3)}$ is true.

$\text{(4)}$: Similar to finding a direct argument that $\text{(3)}$ is true.

---

This should help.

If $(a_n)$ is any sequence such that for all $n$ $a_n \ge 0$ and $b \lt 0$ then the sequence $(a_n)$  can't converge to $b$.

Reason: For sufficiently small $\varepsilon \gt 0$ the open interval $(b-\varepsilon, b+\varepsilon)$ is contained in $(-\infty,0)$ but

$$\quad (-\infty,0) \cap \{a \, | \, a = a_n \text{ for some } n\}= \emptyset$$